# Weight painting in rigging and particle systems combined

Tags: rigging

I modelled and rigged a rabbit. There are many vertexgroups name-connected with the bones. One of the groups is the head and the eyes are included. I made a separate vertex-group for the eyes eventhough they are not connected to the armature but it is just handy to be able to select them (for texturing eg). 
The eyes move with the rig when they are joined to the mesh. But when I apply a particle system (hair) to the head they are also planted on the eyes. So when I then weightpaint the eyes blue in the head, the particles are gone but the eyes don't move with the rig anymore.
So the weightpaint seems to conflict for rigging and particle systems? Is there a way to separate weightpainting for particles and for rigging?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! There was one thing I forgot to try and that was adding bones for the eyes. Eventhough I did not plan to animate the eyes this probably is the only way to do it. Made 2 eye bones and 2 vertexgroups with the same name. The eyes move with the rig now and there is no hair on the eyes.